# How do I insert scales in my geom_area graphic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, scale

I'm coding a graphic and I'm giving the scales Y that I want to plot, but when I plot it the scales is wrong. See it:

```
ggplot(pop_idade_escolar_americana, aes(x = Ano, y = De.0a5.anos)) +
  geom_area( fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.4) +
  geom_line(color="#69b3a2", size=2) +
  geom_point(size=3, color="#69b3a2") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(10000, 11000, 13000, 14000),
                     labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".")) +
  labs(y = NULL,
       x = NULL) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum()
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with the plot? This is exactly the scale that you have asked for with `scale_y_continuous`

Comment: @AllanCameron the problem is the "space" below of the 10.000 scales. Do you see it?

Comment: Try adding `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(9000, 17000))`  to your plot if you don't want the y axis to start at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `geom_ribbon` instead of `geom_area`.

The only differences between the two:

| geom | Required aesthetics | Defaults |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `geom_ribbon` | `x, ymin, ymax` | (none) |
| `geom_area` | `x, y` | `ymin=0` (and `ymax=y`) |

```r
ggplot(pop_idade_escolar_americana, aes(x = Ano, y = De.0a5.anos)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = -Inf, ymax = De.0a5.anos), fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.4) +
  geom_line(color="#69b3a2", size=2) +
  geom_point(size=3, color="#69b3a2") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(10000, 11000, 13000, 14000),
                     labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".")) +
  labs(y = NULL,
       x = NULL) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum()
```

The use of `ymin = -Inf` uses ggplot's default expansion of the axis, so it'll be "a little" below the minimum observed value. Some alternatives for defining `ymin`:

- literal `ymin = 9000` (may be inside or outside `aes(..)`)
- manual offset `ymin = min(De.0a5.anos) - 500` (must be inside `aes(..)`), the offset may be nothing (just `min(..)`) if you desire